# Can't mount filesystem on HD that came from WD NAS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery, nas

I have a WD NAS drive, I need to recover some deleted files, so I've taken the drive out and plugged it into an Ubuntu machine to get direct access to the filesystem...

When I check the drive in `parted` I see:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD20EURS-63S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 3      15.7MB  528MB   513MB                primary
 1      528MB   2576MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 2      2576MB  4624MB  2048MB  ext3         primary  raid
 4      4624MB  2000GB  1996GB  ext4         primary
```

However, when I try mounting `/dev/sdb4` with ext4...

```
root# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb4 /media/2TB
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb4,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Any ideas why it wont mount?

Edit: When mounting without -t (for all partitions):

```
root# mount /dev/sdb /media/2TB
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root# mount /dev/sdb1 /media/2TB
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
root# mount /dev/sdb2 /media/2TB
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
root# mount /dev/sdb3 /media/2TB
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root# mount /dev/sdb4 /media/2TB
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb4,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: The likelihood seems pretty low, but is it possible the kernel is missing ext4 support?

Comment: Looks like your NAS is using some sort of RAID, do you know what kind?  Presumably its mirrored.

Comment: There's only 1 drive in the NAS, so I really doubt there was any RAID going on... (it's a 2TB WD "MyBook Live" drive).

Comment: Also, mkfs.ext4 is available as a command, so I believe ext4 is there...

Comment: Yea but you have raid flags in the first 2 partitions. Have you tried mounting it without specifying `-t`

Comment: I just edited the question to show what happens when I try without -t.

Comment: I should note that I am unfamiliar as to how to mount raid partitions...

Comment: I did however notice that /dev/sd1 and /dev/sd2 are the NAS's OS and are both identical.....  but I'm looking for the data volume...

Comment: Is it possible that the partition is false-flagged as ext4 when it is in fact something else, like ntfs (which is fairly common in NAS boxes)?

Comment: I tried mounting it with ext2, ext3, ext4, ntfs, vfat, xfs...  no dice

Comment: It looks like even without the raid flag, the 4th partition may be raid (in spite of being not used for raid...) http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/forum/t-90514/how-to-recover-data-from-wd-my-book-world-edition-nas-device

Comment: When I try running `mdadm --assemle /dev/md4 /dev/sdb4` it throws `mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb4 mdadm: /dev/sdb4 has no superblock - assembly aborted`

Comment: Any updates on this please Ian? Have a drive here with similar symptoms...

Comment: Sorry, this happened a while ago, I think the solution I used was to just kill the RAID and reformat...  I don't remember though.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming you need the [mdadm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) Linux software raid utility to deal with the partition #4 listed below from the [WD Rescue procedure 2](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/rescue-procedure-take-2) web page. It is likely it is part of a software RAID array even if it is on a single disk. We see this on the Seagate NAS as well.

Your partition table should look like this:

- Unallocated space. (This space is used to store individual system specific data, such as MAC address, serial number, etc.)
- Partition #1, formatted as ext3. (This is the boot partition, with /boot, /root, etc. on it.)
- Partition #2, formatted as swap (This is the system paging file.)
- Partition #3, formatted as ext3 (This is the rest of the O/S, /var, etc.)
- Partition #4, unknown format. (This is the data-store, don't modify or change this!)

The Partition #4 will likely need to be mounted as a RAID array. It is leaking the file system format of ext4 through but is probably still a RAID partition. Take a look at the above website for details on recovering a software raid partition.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this guide](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/forum/t-308252/how-to:install-debian-on-a-clean-hard-drive-for-the-white-li). It’s worth to read the whole site, it’s very useful.

The command(s) you are searching for:

```
# if your filesystem is corrupted run this, then mkfs...    
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1          

# creating /dev/md0    
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --raid-devices=2 --level=raid1 --run --metadata=0.90 /dev/sdb1 missing
```

- assumed that your drive is `/dev/sdb`.
- I recommend to read the guide before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because of non-standard block size, need to mounting via fuseext2 instead of via system mount:

```
sudo fuseext2 -o ro -o sync_read /dev/sdb4 /mnt/data
```

In my case, with WD MyBookLive (single 1TB drive), both system partitions (sdb, sdb, 2GB) and the data partition (sdb4) refused to mount due to non-standard block size. The symptom for the data partition was "unrecovered read error, relocation failed" despite successfull fsck. Also, the RAID flag on system partitions was a false flag: no mdadm was needed to mount them, both mounted with fuseext2.

Credit: https://john-hunt.com/2013/04/25/recovering-data-from-a-wd-mybook-live-2tb-3tbor-similar